# Set an Elements Visibility Based on Cell Value of Bound Datatable

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, hyperlink, datatable

I'm trying to figure out a way in which a cell in a GridView is *visible* based on it's associated column in the bound `DataTable`. The issue I believe I'm having is that this table is dynamic and perhaps as rows are added to the table, the table is not being re-populated/re-freshed on the asp page.

Here is the scenario:
I have a table, for example, of three columns and one row. Column 1 is the index, column 2 is a name, column 3 is true or false which is meant to set the visibility of a link in the asp page.

Row 1 is already set as `1, John Doe, false` so on the asp page all you see is

> 1 | John Doe

You can hit a drop down, click a name, and then add this name to the datatable. By default column 3 is inserted with a `true` value. So after the row is inserted into the table the row is reflected on the asp page as so

> 1 | John Doe
>   2 | Jane Doe

But because column 3 is true, I would like a 'delete' button to be visible so the asp page would instead look something like this

> 1 | John Doe
>   2 | Jane Doe | Delete

Where 'Delete' is a link for deleting that newly inserted row.

I've found [this](http://forums.asp.net/t/2028505.aspx?trying%20to%20hide%20gridview%20column%20based%20on%20database%20value%20) thinking this is exactly what I need but the 'Delete' link still fails to display in the GridView.

What am I overlooking so that I can simply display an `asp:LinkButton` (or any link equivalent) based on a cell value in a `DataTable`?

### Edit

Addition of RowDataBound eventhandler function.

```
protected void NamesGV_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e) {
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header) {
        for (int i = 0; i < e.Row.Cells.Count; i++) {
            e.Row.Cells[i].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Beige; ;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have any code to share? You probably want to evaluate your third data value in the GridView.RowDataBound event handler and insert your LinkButton at that time. Alternatively, you could include the LinkButton and default it to hidden then change visibility of the control in the RowDataBound.

Comment: I can share plenty of code, it's just a little scattered throughout the app. What part of the code would help you help me, specifically @mjw?

Comment: Perhaps the GridView markup and the aforementioned RowDataBound event handler? This is how I would approach your problem as described, but perhaps you're doing something in a way that won't mesh with that approach.

Comment: I was kind of already on your alternative path, where I include the linkbutton by default and set it to hidden. So I would need to change visibility in the RowDataBound event. I'll edit my original to include what I have in that function so far but it's not much, @mjw.

Comment: Here's something similar to what you want to do: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23680973/gridview-disable-edit-delete-if-column-has-value though you'll be changing the visibility instead of disabling it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So something like this...not tested so you may need to tweak it a bit:

```
 protected void NamesGV_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e) 
 {
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header) 
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < e.Row.Cells.Count; i++) 
        {
            e.Row.Cells[i].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Beige;
        }
    }

    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
         //Get reference to the button you want to hide/show
         LinkButton delButton = CType(e.Row.Cells(2).FindControl("lbYourLinkButtonId"), LinkButton);

         //check your data for value
         bool visible = (bool)DoACheckForAValue(NamesGV.DataKeys(e.Row.RowIndex).Value);
         delButton.Visible = visible;
    }
}
```

Comment: It did require tweaking but I got it to work. I'm hoping the next challenge, of linking this now visible delete button to a function which actually deletes that respective row, will not be very difficult.

Comment: Glad you got it working! Linking it up to a Command shouldn't be too bad. Look in to making your LinkButton column a TemplateColumn and use CommandName and CommandArgument to pass your action and ID of item to delete.